# Apache2 Failed to start after installing php5 alonside php7 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, php5, php7

I am running **Apache2** with **php7** on **Ubuntu 16.04**. But alongside this, I had installed **php5**.

- After installation of **php5** I executed `sudo a2enmod php5.6`
- Then I restarted **apache2** with `sudo service apache2 restart`

But **Apache2** won't start.

After running `systemctl status apache2.service` I am getting:

```
    ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-10-19 20:07:51 BST; 6s ago
  Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 7656 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 7748 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILU

Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik apache2[7748]:  *
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik apache2[7748]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik apache2[7748]: Output of config test was:
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik apache2[7748]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik apache2[7748]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik apache2[7748]: The Apache error log may have more informat
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 19 20:07:51 tulik systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code
```

Comment: What does the end of `/var/log/apache2/error_log` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that **I didn't disabled php7.0 mod**.

I run `sudo a2dimod php7.0` and everything works fine now.

Now can switch between versions of **PHP**  easily.